# Macbook went over 95C

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

My MacBook just went over 95 °C/100 °C. I am scared that it might break my MacBook. I cleaned the MacBook screen and stuff but every time I do something on it, it instantly heats up very high. Should I be concerned or is this normal(that I doubt)?

MacBook:

- Apple - MacBook Pro - 13" Display with Touch Bar
- Intel Core i5
- 16GB Memory
- 512GB SSD
- Space Gray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the CPU specs [here](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196594/intel-core-i51038ng7-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html) on Intel's website, but the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die (Tjunction) for the i5-1038NG7 (which may be your CPU) is 100 °C.

Here is a [description](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005597/processors.html) (from Intel) of what the Tjunction max temperature means:

**What is Tjunction max temperature?**

> Tjunction max is the maximum thermal junction temperature that a
> processor will allow prior to using internal thermal control
> mechanisms to reduce power and limit temperature. Activation of the
> processor's thermal control system may cause performance loss as the
> processor typically reduces frequency and power to prevent
> overheating. The goal for a system builder or a do-it-yourself (DIY)
> end user is to design a platform configuration that keeps the
> processor under the Tjunction max threshold during heavy workloads to
> maximize performance of the system.

I suspect that your machine is fine, as thermal throttling should occur at the CPU level as needed. Also from the Intel Support site:

**Could my processor get damaged from overheating?**

> It's unlikely that a
> processor would get damaged from overheating, due to the operational
> safeguards in place. Processors have two modes of thermal protection,
> throttling and automatic shutdown. When a core exceeds the set
> throttle temperature, it will reduce power to maintain a safe
> temperature level. The throttle temperature can vary by processor and
> BIOS settings. If the processor is unable to maintain a safe operating
> temperature through throttling actions, it will automatically shut
> down to prevent permanent damage.

You can download the [Intel Power Gadget](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-power-gadget.html) and monitor the temperature your CPU is attaining under load to have a better idea of what is happening. While running under load, you can visually see the thermal throttling occurring - the Power utilization, Frequency, and Temperature will fluctuate when running a consistent high load.

FWIW, I can get my machine up to 96-97 °C by running a load test (code is below). I increased the number of parallel processes to 16 (on an 8-Core Intel i9), though it is 4 in the below bash shell code fragment.

```
for i in {1..4}
do
        yes > /dev/null &
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think this is normal. My MacBook Air often goes over 95 °C when using Blender, building on Roblox Studio, or any other CPU-intensive things.

Comment: Well, what would be the maximum temperature then? 115C?

Comment: I think 105 C is the safe limit.

Comment: well no. apple programmed MacBooks to shut down when cpu temp goes above 215 F

Answer (score 0):

Though this is normal, it can be scary and/or lead to thermal throttling.

To prematurely spin up the fan (for example, at 70 °C), you can use Macs Fan Control, found [here](https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control). You can create custom rules that auto-launch on bootup. It's a set-it-and-forget-it thing.

Comment: I always spin up my fans to at least 5000 RPM, it still goes hot.